# Toggle a class of active first-child jQuery/CSS3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an unordered list, I want to be able to toggle the a class of active only if its the first child in the list.

I am using jQueryUI sortable, so when I drag and move the li around i always want the first li to have the class of active and if they swap over, ie drag the last li to the first li the class active is always on the first li and the other switches off?

How can i achieve this? Can it be done pure CSS3 or jQuery?

Comment: What is the purpose of the class? Is it just for styling? If it's always first, do you really need a class?

Comment: Like Crazy Train suggest, if purpose of class active is just styling, use only CSS

Comment: sortable has an complete function. use it to remove all "first" classes and add the "first" class to the first child. use :first-child selector in CSS3 if you just need it for styling